# Truffle uint test script not reflecting updated storage variable, and strange behaviour

Tags: unit-testing, solidity, truffle

```
uint256 public burningRatePercent = 50;
    function onlyOwnerSetBurningRate(uint256 _burningRatePercent) onlyOwner public returns (uint)
    {
        burningRatePercent = _burningRatePercent;
        return (burningRatePercent);
    }

//and the test script is 

it("should return set value from onlyOwnerSetBurningRate", function() {
    var token;
    return Token.deployed().then(function(instance){
        token = instance;
        const tst = token.onlyOwnerSetBurningRate.call(1234);
        return tst;
    }).then(function(result){
        assert.equal(result.toNumber(), 1234, 'onlyOwnerSetBurningRate failed');
        var ret =  token.burningRatePercent.call();
        return ret;
    }).then(function(result){
        assert.equal(result.toNumber(), 1234, 'Reading BurningRate set value failed');
    }); 
}); 

//and this code below also produces same problem
    it("should return set value from onlyOwnerSetBurningRate", async function() {
        var token;
        token = await Token.deployed();
        const tst = await token.onlyOwnerSetBurningRate.call(1234);
        assert.equal(tst.toNumber(), 1234, 'onlyOwnerSetBurningRate failed');
        const tst2 = await token.burningRatePercent();
        assert.equal(tst2.toNumber(), 1233, 'onlyOwnerSetBurningRate failed');      
    });

even after updating public variable 'burningRatePercent' it shows old value
```

while testing I got a strange behavior of truffle, please see the subject smart contract code first
    My question is straight forward if return of 'tst' is '1234' then why return of 'ret' is 50 ?

in the test code burningRatePercent should return '1234' for 'tst2' variable but it is 50
please do not explain any other way of doing or the explanation which I am not looking for, just I need answer, why tst2 is returning '50', why not '1234' ?

Answer (score 0):

You should send a transaction, not call.

This statement is wrong, it doesn't send a transaction thus doesn't modify `burningRatePercent`:

```
token.onlyOwnerSetBurningRate.call(1234)
```

See [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send) for the correct way of sending a transaction.

In a nutshell: `call` for read-only operations on blockchain and `send` for the rest.

Comment: its truffle test script, and call() is working, because I am getting correct return tst = '1234' in that line but not in tst2 which is 50 ?, I read in some article that truffle framework translates call() to send as necessary

Comment: Well, I do smart contract development as a job, so I'm very sure. Just visit the link and read the difference between call and send, and your confusion will disappear.

Comment: no no `const tst2 = await token.burningRatePercent();` this is the subject line another way to do the same, where is call(), this also returns 50 why ? I think instead of rising question on Truffle Bug, you are rising my knowledge, my question is straight forward, I am not looking for answer you replied , its a kind of bug with truffle, if not please explain, how it is no ? Thank You